Keyword Term: What is the psychological term for a person who in teenage years shows no interest in sex or peer socialization
Normal development:

At puberty, boys begin to show an interest in girls (or boys) as being different/wonderful.  They start to see them as possible sexual/romantic partners

In middle childhood, friend groups are mostly about shared interests and shared activities.  In adolescence friend groups are more about shared feelings and intimate thoughts.


https://courses.lumenlearning.com/adolescent/chapter/peer-relationships/
Same article goes on to say

Peer relationships are particularly important for children. They can be supportive but also challenging. Peer rejection may lead to behavioral problems later in life. However, peer relationships can be challenging, as well as supportive (Rubin, Coplan, Chen, Bowker, & McDonald, 2011). Being accepted by other children is an essential source of affirmation and self-esteem.

What is it called when a person doesn't make this transition, does not see other people as potential partners, does not engage as a teenager in shared feelings and intimate thoughts, does not engage with peers to any significant degree?
This is likely to be not just one term, but several.

Some possibilities: https://www.healthline.com/health/mental-health/asocial-vs-antisocial-vs-introverted

For sex specifically there is asexuality which may or may not involve interest in romantic relationships, but what you describe in the body of the question seems to go further.
